# Copy selected text n times using vim editor

Tags: vim, copy-paste

How is it possible to copy multiple lines and paste them 'n' number of times using vi editor.

For example:

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
```

Now I would like to copy the 3 lines as they are 100 times one after the other like:

```
#First copy
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
#Second copy
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
...
...
```

Comment: I tried to format your question but I wasn't sure about your actual goal. Could you reformat it using proper markdown?

Comment: You can use motion before `p`. Yank 3 lines using `3y` and paste using `100p`

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for hours. I tried to yank using "yy" and it could copy only the specified line. Thanks!!

Comment: @SaideepPavuluri: I've posted an answer. Do accept it if you find it useful

Answer (score 3):

Vim has a concept called **count** that helps to iterate a lot of commands.

In this case, yanking and pasting can be used with count.

<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> will yank 3 lines.
<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> will paste those lines 100 times.

run `:h count` to learn more

> An optional number that may precede the command to multiply
>   or iterate the command.  If no number is given, a count of one
>   is used, unless otherwise noted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to copy those three consecutive lines:

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
```

and paste them three-by-three like this:

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
...
```

and your cursor is on the first line, you can achieve your goal with a mix of Ex commands and normal mode commands like this:

```
3:y<CR>jj99p
```

which expands to:

```
:.,.+2y<CR>jj99p
```

or like this with a visual-line selection:

```
Vjjy99p
```

or like this if you know the line numbers:

```
:1,3y|3|normal! 99p<CR>
```

or like this if you want to use the "paragraph" text-object and motion:

```
yip}99p
```

or simply:

```
3yjj99p
```

And I'm sure you could find a dozen more ways.

Comment: `99P` instead of the `jj99p`?

Comment: @FDinoff, yes that is what I would do in that case.